# disable option highlighted while appended

Tags: jquery

I am appending a disabled option into a `<select>` box, I have a slight issue though. If I append the options in the `<select>`, one of the options remains highlighted, which doesn't seem like a big deal but it doesn't look good when one disabled option is highlighted and obviously other options can't be highlighted.

How can I remove the highlight when options are appended? Below is code:

```
var selectedOption = $('select#studentadd');
$('select#studentselect').append(selectedOption.html()).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be that is what you wanted:

```js
var selectedOption = $('select#studentadd');
$("select#studentselect").append(selectedOption.html()).attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("select#studentselect option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
```

Working jsFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/u6V9s/)

Answer (score 0):

To clear selected options in a `select` the easiest is to set the value of `select` to empty string using `val()`

```
$('select#studentselect').val('').append(selectedOption.html()).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: Hi, I tried you line of code but it is still highlighting the last option appended when the data is appended

Comment: put val() at end then if the options from previous select were selected